# How to set the label names when using the Huggingface TextClassificationPipeline?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers

I am using a fine-tuned Huggingface model (on my company data) with the [TextClassificationPipeline](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/pipelines.html#transformers.TextClassificationPipeline) to make class predictions. Now the labels that this `Pipeline` predicts defaults to `LABEL_0`, `LABEL_1` and so on. Is there a way to supply the label mappings to the `TextClassificationPipeline` object so that the output may reflect the same?

> Env:
>
> - tensorflow==2.3.1
> - transformers==4.3.2

Sample Code:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'  # or any {'0', '1', '2'}

from transformers import TextClassificationPipeline, TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification, AutoTokenizer

MODEL_DIR = "path\to\my\fine-tuned\model"

# Feature extraction pipeline
model = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL_DIR)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_DIR)

pipeline = TextClassificationPipeline(model=model,
                                      tokenizer=tokenizer,
                                      framework='tf',
                                      device=0)

result = pipeline("It was a good watch. But a little boring.")[0]
```

Output:

```
In [2]: result
Out[2]: {'label': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.8864616751670837}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The simplest way is to add such a mapping is to edit the config.json of the model to contain: `id2label` field as below:

```
{
  "_name_or_path": "distilbert-base-uncased",
  "activation": "gelu",
  "architectures": [
    "DistilBertForMaskedLM"
  ],
  "id2label": [
    "negative",
    "positive"
  ],
  "attention_dropout": 0.1,
  .
  .
}
```

A in-code way to set this mapping is by adding the `id2label` param in the `from_pretrained` call as below:

```
model = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL_DIR, id2label={0: 'negative', 1: 'positive'})
```

Here is the [Github Issue](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/10940) I raised for this to get added into the Documentation of transformers.XForSequenceClassification.

Comment: The setting of such config params is actually well documented [here](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/configuration.html)